# Can I Keep Test Ads on For My Specific device?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have a quick question regarding test ads. I have an app in the IOS AppStore that is using Google AdMob. I received an email today saying that my account was temporarily suspended for clicking on my own ads. I had test ads enabled in development to prevent just this; however, I removed the test ads in my final release.

My question is: Can I keep test ads on for my specific device?

In my code I have:

`request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "My Device ID" ]`

Since the ID is specific to my device can I leave it there in an AppStore release? or Will this cause issues in the future?

I just want to make sure I don't get a permanent suspension. Thanks!

-Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the ID is specific to my device can I leave it there in an AppStore release? or Will this cause issues in the future?

Yes, you can leave your device ID in the `testDevices` field for release, and it is in fact required by AdMob guidelines (as you seem to have found out).  Since the ID is specific to your device, it will not cause any problems.